# Jquery class selector is not working in ASP.Net Gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, gridview

Using the below code I am trying to write some validation code on change event of dropdown "ddlAction".

I have tried few ways e.g.

1. `$(".ddlAction").change(function () {`
2. `$("#grdApproval").find("[id^='ddlAction']").change(function () {`
3. `$("input[id*=ddlAction]").change(function ()`
4. `$("input[value*=ddlAction]").change(function () {`

   1. --> Works only if I am on gridview's page one.

C# Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTION" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAction" CssClass="ddlAction" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="150px" SkinID="GridEdit" ValidationGroup="Compensation" Enabled="true"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

JQuery :

```
$(function () {
    $(".ddlAction").change(function () {
    //$("#grdApproval").find("[id*='ddlAction']").change(function () {
    //$("input[id*=ddlAction]").change(function () {
    //$("input[value*=ddlAction]").change(function () {
        //do something;
    });
});
```

Page source :

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdApproval$ctl03$ddlAction" id="MainContent_grdApproval_ddlAction_1" class="ddlAction" style="color:Black;background-color:#FFFF99;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:9pt;width:150px;">
<option value="97" title="-----------Select-----------">-----------Select-----------</option>
<option value="FS" title="Finalize-Submit">Finalize-Submit</option>
<option value="NMR" title="Needs More Research">Needs More Research</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$(".ddlAction").on('change', function () {

})
```

should work. it will attach on change event to every .ddlAction drop down on the page , not just table

You are not showing gridview id, I consider it to be '#grdApproval'

So your code better be changed to:

```
$('#grdApproval').on('change','.ddlAction', function() {

})
```

this way it will use event delegation.

It might not work pages other than first in case you are using callbacks for gridview, or wrapped gridview in UpdatePanel

In both of this cases you need to re-set handler after async-postback

UPDATE: In case you have update panel you need to do the following:

```
   // lets say you have function that you call to init your page:

   function myInit() {
       $('#grdApproval').on('change','.ddlAction', function() {

       }) 
   }

   // and you calling it on page load
   $(document).ready(myInit)


   // add the following line, to run the same code on pageLoaded
   // for async postback driven by UpdatePanel 

   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(myInit);
```

Comment: Yes, I Gird is inside UpdatePanel. Would you please suggest me how to re-set handler after async-postback ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked and issue fixed by re-attaching event after async-postback

## JQuery:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ddlAction").change(function () {
        var HFStatusChangedId = this.id.replace("ddlAction", "HFStatusChanged");
        if (this.selectedIndex !== "97") {
            document.getElementById(HFStatusChangedId).value = "Y";
        }
    });
});
```

}