# Jquery FadeIn FadeOut works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have `LinkButton` which on click shows `asp:panel` which contains image and close button. the panel id is `LinkButton1` and the close button id inside this panel is `close` It works fine except the `FadeIn` fires only once. If I refresh the whole page it works again but I don't want to the users to refresh to be able to `fadein/fadeout` the panel repeatedly.

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="navButtons" >Restorant</asp:LinkButton>

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
                $('#Viewer').fadeIn(1000);
            });

            $('#close').click(function () {
                $('#Viewer').fadeOut(1000);

            });
        });


<body >

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Viewer" CssClass="Viewer">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ViewerImage" CssClass="ImageV" ImageUrl="~/Hotel/as.jpg" />
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="close" CssClass="close" ImageUrl="~/Background/close.jpg" />                
        </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: can you provide more html? Where is the `#close`? I created a demo from what you had and it appears to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fb659v1o/

Comment: if dom elements are dynamically created and destroyed you will want to use bind method http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: try using `toggle()` instead

Comment: hmm it works in your demo indeed but mine doesnt still can;t find the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following in case you are experiencing event bind issues:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#LinkButton1', function(){
        $('#Viewer').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#close', function(){
        $('#Viewer').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice we had the same idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you bind the the function to the body instead

```
$(function {
    $('body').on('click', '#LinkButton1', function () {
        $('#Viewer').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#close', function () {
        $('#Viewer').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your link button is outside of your body element, which is wrong.

Second, by default ASP.NET elements ID does not match `id` of DOM elements that they are rendered to.

In order to get real ID use ClientID propert:

```
var lbId = '#<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>'
  , viewerId = '#<%= Viewer.ClientID %>'
  , closeId = '#<%= close.ClientID %>'


$(function() {
   var lb = $(lbId)
     , viewer = $(viewerId)
     , close = $(closeId)

   lb.on('click', viewer.fadeIn.bind(viewer, 1000))
   close.on('click', viewer.fadeOut.bind(viewer, 1000))
})
```

In case your code in reality is inside updatepanel or something, that actually changes DOM and puts elements in and takes elements out of DOM , you have two option:

- use event delegation in jQuery
- subscribe to events of UpdatePanel

For event delegation change your code to:

```
var lbId = '#<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>'
  , viewerId = '#<%= Viewer.ClientID %>'
  , closeId = '#<%= close.ClientID %>'


$(function() {
   var body = $('body')        
     , viewer = $(viewerId)
   body.on('click', lbId ,  viewer.fadeIn.bind(viewer, 1000))
   body.on('click', closeId , viewer.fadeOut.bind(viewer, 1000))
})
```

If you do have updatepanel and for some reason do not want to use event delegation, use code from this answer: [Jquery class selector is not working in ASP.Net Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000345/jquery-class-selector-is-not-working-in-asp-net-gridview/24000486#24000486)